# Where can i find nlp-compromise architecture diagram?

Tags: nlp, nlp-compromise

I came across with very interesting project on git hub [**nlp-compromise/compromise**](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise).

I want to know how it works but cant find any documentation about its architecture or how it works on back-end.

Comment: The slack group or the mailing list on the github repo should be the right channel to your question.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, we've been working hard on the docs the past-few months.

Hope this hits the spot:

https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise/wiki/How-it-Works